# MYSQL query on products within variant price range without duplicates

Tags: mysql, semi-join

I am trying to query my products table such that my query returns a product set within a certain variant price range -- products have many variants and variants belong to products.  I have the following query which is working but it is very slow -- the query takes 1.66 seconds.

```
SELECT colortags.tag, products.*, (SELECT variants.price FROM variants WHERE variants.product_id = products.product_id LIMIT 1) price, collects.position 
FROM products
INNER JOIN wp_wps_collects collects 
ON products.product_id = collects.product_id 
AND collects.collection_id = 123456788
INNER JOIN wp_wps_tags colortags 
ON colortags.product_id = collects.product_id 
AND (colortags.tag = 'black' OR colortags.tag = 'nav') 
INNER JOIN wp_wps_tags styletags 
ON styletags.product_id = collects.product_id 
AND (styletags.tag = 'purses')
WHERE (SELECT variants.price FROM variants WHERE variants.product_id = products.product_id AND variants.price >= 200 AND variants.price < 300 LIMIT 1) > 0
AND (SELECT variants.price FROM variants WHERE variants.product_id = products.product_id AND variants.price >= 200 AND variants.price < 300 LIMIT 1) <> 0
```

In the `WHERE` statement, I've tried just checking the `price` value created by my subquery in my SELECT statement but MYSQL tells me that `price` is undefined. Here's the SQL:

```
SELECT colortags.tag, products.*, (SELECT variants.price FROM wp_wps_variants variants WHERE variants.product_id = products.product_id LIMIT 1) price, collects.position 
FROM wp_wps_products products
INNER JOIN wp_wps_collects collects 
ON products.product_id = collects.product_id 
AND collects.collection_id = 98515058801
INNER JOIN wp_wps_tags colortags 
ON colortags.product_id = collects.product_id 
AND (colortags.tag = 'color:generic-black' OR colortags.tag = 'color:navy') 
INNER JOIN wp_wps_tags styletags 
ON styletags.product_id = collects.product_id 
AND (styletags.tag = 'style:totes')
WHERE price >= 200 
AND price < 300
```

This is the error message I get from the immediately above SQL:

> Unknown column 'price' in 'where clause'

I've also tried to use a series of joins on the `variants` table but then I get duplicate products returned. Here's the SQL

```
SELECT colortags.tag, products.*, (SELECT variants.price FROM variants WHERE variants.product_id = products.product_id LIMIT 1) price, collects.position 
FROM products
INNER JOIN collects 
ON products.product_id = collects.product_id 
AND collects.collection_id = 1234566
INNER JOIN colortags 
ON colortags.product_id = collects.product_id 
AND (colortags.tag = 'black' OR colortags.tag = 'navy') 
INNER JOIN styletags 
ON styletags.product_id = collects.product_id 
AND (styletags.tag = 'purses')
INNER JOIN variants
ON variants.product_id = products.product_id
AND variants.price >= 200 
AND variants.price < 300
AND variants.price > 0
AND variants.price <> 0
```

What I would like is the query results obtained from the first SQL statement without the performance hit. I'd like to think that I can write   SQL with an `INNER JOIN` on the variants table to filter out variants of the incorrect price without getting duplicate products but I cannot identify how.

Does anyone know how I can write SQL here that would allow me to query products within a certain variant price range without getting duplicate products back and without a serious performance hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a *semi-join*, which means you want to do a join but you only want one row of result, even if there are multiple matches.

One way you can do this is to join to a derived table, which uses GROUP BY in a subquery to reduce the variants to one row per product_id.

```
SELECT colortags.tag, products.*, prices.price, collects.position 
FROM products
INNER JOIN wp_wps_collects collects 
  ON products.product_id = collects.product_id 
  AND collects.collection_id = 123456788
INNER JOIN wp_wps_tags colortags 
  ON colortags.product_id = collects.product_id 
  AND (colortags.tag = 'black' OR colortags.tag = 'nav') 
INNER JOIN wp_wps_tags styletags 
  ON styletags.product_id = collects.product_id 
  AND (styletags.tag = 'purses')
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT v.product_id, MIN(v.price) AS price FROM variants v
  INNER JOIN wp_wps_collects c ON v.product_id = c.product_id
  WHERE c.collection_id = 123456788
  GROUP BY product_id ORDER BY NULL
) prices
  ON products.product_id = prices.product_id
```

I assumed you'd be interested in the minimum price per product. You could alternatively use `MAX()` in the derived table.

I had to duplicate the join to `wp_wps_collects` so the derived table would be limited to products relevant to the collection you're querying. Otherwise if you have millions of products, the derived table would become so large that it would create a different performance problem.

Comment: thank you so much for this answer. I think it's the one I want. I tested it and it works when I add after, `ON products.product_id = prices.product_id`, the following `WHERE` statement to filter down the set of products I'm looking for within a price range `WHERE prices.price >= 200 AND prices.price < 300` -- `200` and `300` are arbitrary values of course.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I forgot to add the WHERE clause. But you figured it out. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you encapsulate your query inside another, you can use `price` in `where` clause

```
SELECT * from (
    SELECT colortags.tag, products.*, (SELECT variants.price FROM variants WHERE variants.product_id = products.product_id LIMIT 1) price, collects.position 
    FROM products
    INNER JOIN wp_wps_collects collects 
    ON products.product_id = collects.product_id 
    AND collects.collection_id = 123456788
    INNER JOIN wp_wps_tags colortags 
    ON colortags.product_id = collects.product_id 
    AND (colortags.tag = 'black' OR colortags.tag = 'nav') 
    INNER JOIN wp_wps_tags styletags 
    ON styletags.product_id = collects.product_id 
    AND (styletags.tag = 'purses')
    WHERE (SELECT variants.price FROM variants WHERE variants.product_id = products.product_id AND variants.price >= 200 AND variants.price < 300 LIMIT 1) > 0
) t 
WHERE t.price >= 200 and t.price < 300
```

Comment: thank you @Simonare for your answer. With this `where` statement, `WHERE (SELECT variants.price FROM variants WHERE variants.product_id = products......` in the encapsulated query the query is correct but almost a second long.  However if you remove, the query is 10 milliseconds and accurate. 

If you remove the above `where` statement I am referencing I will accept your answer.